# All HTML tags are automatically stripped from views block when placed inside a <select> element

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, theming

I'm trying to use Views to create a custom block which will display the linked titles of all content of type "promotion" in a dropdown menu. Every result's title is displayed within an `<option>` tag whose value attribute is the URL of the result. The block is then displayed within a region called "promotion_menu" which is placed within an existing `<select>` element.

```
<select class="mobnav" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
 <option value="/">Home</option>
 <optgroup label="About">
  <option value="/lessons">Lessons</option>
  <option value="/technology">Technology</option>
  <option value="/custom-fitting">Custom Fitting</option>
 </optgroup>
 <optgroup label="Learning">
  <option value="/category/1">Tips & Articles</option>
  <option value="/blog">Blog</option>
 </optgroup>
 <optgroup label="Enquire">
  <option value="/contact">Contact Us</option>
  <option value="/events">Corporate Events</option>
  <option value="/partners">Partners & Affilliates</option>
 </optgroup>
 <optgroup label="Events">
  <?php print render($page['promotion_menu']); ?>
 </optgroup>
</select>
```

The block itself works as expected when the region is placed outside the `<select>` element IE a series of option tags containing the relevant titles is displayed. However, when placed inside the element all the html tags are stripped and replaced with whitespace and the entire block is enclosed in quotation "" marks.

[image: The view, which normally displays correctly, shows only plain text with no HTML tags. The content links have been removed in this example.]

Is there a template doing this or is this just inherent behavior of the `<select>` tag which I have simply overlooked? I have tried it in its own `<select>` tag and have tried disabling AdBlocker to no avail.

Comment: An `<optgroup>` allows zero or more `<option>` tags as children, and nothing else.

Comment: The block only prints out `<option>` tags. My problem is that the `<option>` tags are stripped and only quoted plaintext remains. Even if it were printing something else it would still display in the inspector.

Comment: Not necessarily, Chrome (I'm assuming Chrome from the markup colouring) tends to react unpredictably when it finds HTML it thinks is in the wrong place - are you sure your region and block aren't being rendered with the usual wrapping tags? Unless you've specifically overridden that region and block template its likely they are, and it could easily explain the problem you see in dev tools

Comment: Completely forgot about the wrapping tags for the region! Also tried putting invalid html within an '<optgroup>' on a test page and it produced the exact same result as with Drupal so it looks as if that will solve it, thanks a lot!